# Is there an elegant way to use the app timezone when running a Rails ActiveRecord aggregate method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When I use an ActiveRecord object's time field or use `pluck` on that field, I always (correctly) get back the time in the application's timezone:

```
> ClaritySurveyData::SurveyResponse.order(:id).first.submitted_at
=> Mon, 17 Sep 2012 09:46:33 PDT -07:00
> ClaritySurveyData::SurveyResponse.order(:id).pluck(:submitted_at).first
=> Mon, 17 Sep 2012 09:46:33 PDT -07:00
```

However, when a use an ActiveRecord aggregate method on the same field, I (incorrectly) get back the time in UTC:

```
> ClaritySurveyData::SurveyResponse.minimum(:submitted_at)
=> 2012-09-17 16:46:33 UTC
```

This bug has been biting me every few years, just infrequently enough that every time I have to figure it out afresh.

Obviously, I can easily work around it in specific cases using `.in_time_zone`.

However, I'd love to be able to patch it generally, so I don't ever have to figure it out again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would say it's because `minimum(:submitted_at)` is using pure SQL (no timezone, everything is recorded as UTC) and `first.submitted_at` is using Ruby/Rails (which handle timezone support). Using ` .in_time_zone` for you case seems the best option in my mind.

Comment: I just test it in rails 6.1.0 and the minimum function works like the others ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Excellent; looking forward to upgrading!! (All my apps are still on Rails 5)